# Use OCaml warning attribute to disable warning 8: unexhaustive match

Tags: attributes, ocaml, warnings

I'm trying to write code similar to the following:

```
let [a; b] =
  (* body *) 
  [1; 2]
```

And I want to disable warning # 8 just for the pattern `[a; b]` and not for the body or for anything outside of the let. I've tried to put the warning attribute to disable the warning, but none of the below work:

```
let[@warning "-8"] [a[@warning "-8"];b[@warning "-8"]] [@warning "-8"] =
  [1;2][@warning "-8"]
[@@ocaml.warning "-8"]
```

P.S. I'm not really writing this code, but am experimenting with a custom PPX preprocessor. So a convoluted but working example is acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local disabling of warnings with `[@warning "…"]` and `[@@warning "…"]`is not well supported for OCaml version anterior to 4.06.0 . For such version, one possibility might be to use enclosing`[@@@warning ""]` attribute:

```
[@@@warning "-8"]
let [a;b] = [1;2]
[@@@warning "+8"]
```

but this also deactivate the warning inside the body.

If you are generating the code and know statiscally the size of the list, another option might be to use a tuple for the binding (aka `let (a,b)= …`)?

Comment: What would be the solution for 4.06.0? Regarding tuples, I'm playing with the idea of allowing something like: `let%exn [a;b;c] = List.map foo [1;2;3]`

Comment: For 4.06, `let@[warning "-8"] [a;b] = (body)[@warning "+8"]` would deactivate the warning  8 on the `[a;b]` binding and reactivate it within the body. Concerning tuple, another exotic option may be type-level sized list (something like `type ('elt, 'size) t = []: ('elt,zero) t | (::): 'elt * ('elt, 'size) t -> ('elt, 'size succ) t`)

Comment: A typo in previous comment: `let@[warning "-8"]` -> `let[@warning "-8"]`.