# Why locally disabling warning about partial application does not seem to work

Tags: ocaml, compiler-warnings

In OCaml 4.08, a new warning about partial applications is emitted by default, as in:

```
let _ = (Format.printf "side-effect!@."; List.iter (fun () -> ()))
```

```
2 |   (Format.printf "side-effect!@."; List.iter (fun () -> ()))
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Warning 5: this function application is partial,
maybe some arguments are missing.
```

Trying to disable it locally by adding annotations everywhere didn't seem to work:

```
let[@warning "-5"] _ [@warning "-5"] =
  (Format.printf "side-effect!@."; List.iter (fun () -> ()))[@@warning "-5"]
```

The only way which works is to use the `[@@@warning "-5"]` technique as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46489249). However, that question mentions that

> Local disabling of warnings with [@warning "…"] and [@@warning "…"]is not well supported for OCaml versions anterior to 4.06.0

What should be the syntax in this case, for OCaml 4.08, to locally disable such warnings?

**Edit**: as suggested by glennsl, replacing `let _ = ...` with `ignore (...)` does offer an alternative (adding `[@@warning "-5"]` after the `ignore (...)` does seem to work), but it is less uniform, since top-level declarations cannot be replaced this way, although they can safely be surrounded with `[@@@warning "-5"]/[@@@warning "+5"]`<sup>1</sup>. Still, it does not explain why my first attempt did not work: is it written incorrectly, is it by design, or possibly an oversight?

<sup>1</sup> *This 'hack' also has the disadvantage of possibly changing the previous state; for instance, if warning 5 had been previously disabled at the global level, this would re-enable it inadvertently.*

Comment: What valid use case is there for disabling this warning? Perhaps your example here is just really contrived, but can you not just use `ignore` instead?

Comment: No, in the real case, the function is used to register data in a hashtable, and it happens to return a function type that is used in some situations, but in others we don't care about it (for instance, registering a callback which you can then store if you want; but the side-effect of its registration is the main use). Using `ignore` does not change it, OCaml 4.08 still emits the warning. The calls are located inside large functions, so disabling warnings inside them entirely is not a good idea, we may miss true positives.

Comment: Wait, I must have mis-tested something, `ignore(...)` followed by `[@@warning "-5"]` does seem to work. It's not as uniform as I'd like (if the `let _ = ...` is at the top level, then syntax `[@@@warning "-5"]`/`[@@@warning "+5"]` is necessary, but should work). Still, I'd like to know why the version with `let _ =` does not work; if it's by design, and if so, why.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't mean you should replace `let _ =` with `ignore`, but just apply it to the part that errors: `ignore (List.iter ...)`. I should think that would work. You might also consider using `let _ : unit -> unit = List.iter ... in ()` to be more explicit about the type and maintain type system guarantees as well as documenting your intention.

Comment: You can wrap it inside a module, if you don't wan't to change the previous state:
```include
      struct
        [@@@ocaml.warning "-5"]
        let _ = ...
      end```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that the following quote from the fine manual (section 8.13.1) indicates that the answer is "by (absence of) design":

> Note that it is not well-defined which scope is used for a specific warning. This is implementation dependant and can change between versions.

Now, if we are trying to interpret why your attempts to silence the warning didn't work, we can check what the warning 5 is about:

> expression whose result has function type and is ignored.

Thus, the warning is emitted when we have a functional expression `e` in a certain context. In the case of `ignore`, the context is simply an application, i.e. an englobing expression, an the scope in which we can ask to forget about warning 5 should be roughly the `ignore` expression itself (and its englobing expressions and item).

Now, for the `let _ = ...`, things are less clear-cut: `e` get ignored when it is bound to the catch-all pattern `_`. One might argue that putting `[@@ warning "-5"]` at the end of the let-binding should cover the whole definition, but as mentioned above, the compiler is perfectly free to disagree with this interpretation.

However, this gives an alternative solution that does not need to disable warning 5 at all: just bind the expression to a variable (starting with an `_` to avoid warning 26, of course):

```
let _i_swear_to_hb_curry_i_know_what_i_m_doing =
  Format.printf "side-effect!@."; List.iter (fun () -> ());;
```

does not trigger any warning: by being bound to such a variable, the expression might still feel a bit neglected, but it can't complain it is actively ignored.